# Issue with JMS + AOP + JNDI Resources

Tags: spring, jms, jndi, spring-aop, spring-jms

Hi and happy new year

I'm working on a project which need to implement jms, aop and some jndi resources.

So far, the project works fine when there are only jms and jndi but when i activated aop, i had some troubles.. here is the configuration :

```
        <!-- JMS implementation -->
<bean id="jmsRefConnectionFactory.activemq" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jms/activeMQConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false" />
    <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsRefQueue.activemq" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jms/activeMQQueue" />
    <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false" />
    <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.jms.Queue" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory.activemq" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="jmsRefConnectionFactory.activemq" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory.activemq" />
    <property name="defaultDestination" ref="jmsRefQueue.activemq" />
    <property name="destinationResolver" ref="jmsDestinationResolver.amq" />
    <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true" />
    <property name="sessionAcknowledgeMode" value="#{T(javax.jms.Session).CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE}" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsRefConnectionFactory.activemq" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsDestinationResolver.amq"
    class="org.springframework.jms.support.destination.DynamicDestinationResolver" />
```

When I start the application, I get this error :

> Caused by: org.springframework.aop.AopInvocationException: AOP configuration seems to be invalid: tried calling method [public abstract javax.jms.Connection javax.jms.ConnectionFactory.createConnection() throws javax.jms.JMSException] on target [org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory@239f 6]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class

Context.xml content :

```
<!-- APACHE MQ -->
<Resource name="jms/activeMQConnectionFactory" auth="Container"
    type="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" description="JMS Connection Factory"
    factory="org.apache.activemq.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory" HOST="localhost"
    PORT="61616" CHAN="" TRAN="1" QMGR="MyQCF" />

<Resource name="jms/activeMQQueue" auth="Container"
    type="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue" description="my Queue"
    factory="org.apache.activemq.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory" physicalName="userQueue" />
```

Web.xml content :

```
 <resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jms/activeMQConnectionFactory</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
  </resource-ref>
  <resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jms/activeMQQueue</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.jms.Queue</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
  </resource-ref>
```

This configuration is OK when aop is not activated but for some reasons, it doesn't work when aop is on..

Spring version : 3.1.2
I'm using activemq (5.7)

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was the problem..

Turns out the aop was not even involved (at least not the configuration that i put). I had some jar in my tomcat server that was not taken for some reasons (i think it's about lib priority/ parent first/last)...

I changed the location and directly put into my project and it works now ! :)